# Find Eulerian trail in D whose vertices are the pairs of integers 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, and whose arcs join ij to kl iff j = k

Tags: graph-theory

Going through *Introduction to Graph Theory 5th Edition* by Robin J Wilson, and question 2.24 states,

> 2.24   Let D be the digraph whose vertices are the pairs of integers 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, and whose arcs join ij to kl if and only if j = k. Find an Eulerian trail in D and use it to obtain a circular arrangement of nine 1s, nine 2s and nine 3s in which each of the 27 possible triples (111, 233, etc.) occurs exactly once. (Problems of this kind arise in communication theory.) (Wilson 46-47)

If I am understanding the problem correctly, I came up with the following incident matrix:
1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0
0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0
0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0
0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1
0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1
0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1

However, I don't see a Eulerian path, a path where you to traverse each edge once and once only and finish at your starting point.

Am I misunderstanding the question? Also, can someone explain what it means obtain a circular arrangement of nine 1s, nine 2s....

Thanks.

Comment: You do not have to finish where you started in an Eulerian trail. There is also a difference between path and trail. A path cannot repeat vertices, a trail can (a trail cannot, however, repeat edges). If a trail (path) is closed, i.e. that you finish where you start, it is called a circuit (cycle). They asked you to find a Eulerian trail, so a trail (perhaps visiting vertices several times but not edges) that traverses each edge of the graph.

Comment: I should have said "I don't see a Eulerian trail" - thank you. Yes, a trail is where all the edges are distinct. Is there a way to determine the trail without the "pen and paper"/tracing method?

Comment: There might be algorithms for this, yes, I am not sure. You would start with asserting that there is an Eulerian trail at all. This requires your graph to have at most two vertices of odd degree. I am a little worried about your incidence matrix. I might be wrong (I haven't used the concept that much) but shouldn't $A_{ij}$ be $1$ if vertex $v_i$ and $e_j$ are incident and $0$ if they are not? Then, in your incidence matrix, the sum of all elements in each column should be $2$. If you have used another convention then restate it in the question.

Comment: Even if you would have used the definition of an incidence matrix described above (corresponding with the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) and forgetting about the column sum not being 2, then every vertex in your graph has degree $3$, meaning an Eulerian trail can't exist. If you have used the definition that $A_{ij}$ is $1$ if $v_i$ is connected to $v_j$, then it should be symmetric. So in any way, you should settle on a definition for the incidence matrix, and redo it. Also, make clear in the question, in what order the vertices are listed in the matrix.

Comment: Thanks - good learning curve here - it's an adjacency matrix. I'll revisit this question entirely.. thanks.

Comment: Ah, of course, adjacency matrix, that was the name I was looking for, where $A_{ij}$ is $1$ if $v_i$ is connected to $v_j$. Well, yes, still in that case there's something wrong. Where the rows and columns supposed to be ordered in the same order as you listed the pairs? (i.e. 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33.) Also, I missed the digraph part =). Sorry, then it does not have to be symmetric. I believe the definition is then that $A_{ij}=1$ if there is an edge from $v_i$ to $v_j$. So the first row of your matrix, provided the order above, would be $(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I also always forget that there is lots of ambiguity regarding definitions within graph theory. Look up, exactly what they mean by trail/path and so on, so that you know precisely what they are looking for. In this case however, trail should be rather universal. Further, in a directed graph G, G has an Euler trail if indegree(x)-outdegree(x)=1 for at most one vertex and outdegree(x)-indegree(x)=1 for at most one, and for every other vertex indeg=outdeg. So it should be fine in your case as each row and column in your a-matrix will have sum 3. Hope you can figure out your original prob. now =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s actually not too hard to draw the nine vertices and $27$ edges of the digraph. Each vertex has in-degree and out-degree $3$, and it’s not too hard just to start somewhere and complete an Euler circuit. In the early stages you can proceed almost arbitrarily; you just have to be careful to leave yourself a way back to the initial vertex. Many circuits are possible; mine starts

$$11,12,21,12,22,22,21,11,13,33,\ldots$$

and ends

$$\ldots,13,31,(11)\;,\tag{1}$$

where the parentheses around $11$ mean that this is actually the first vertex all over again.

Because of the way the edges are defined, adjacent vertices on the circuit ‘interlock’:

$$1\color{crimson}1,\color{crimson}12,2\color{crimson}1,\color{crimson}12,2\color{crimson}2,\color{crimson}22,2\color{crimson}1,\color{crimson}11,1\color{crimson}3,\color{crimson}33,\ldots\;.$$

If you write the vertices of your circuit in order, remove the commas, and then collapse each linking pair to a single digit you get first

$$1\color{crimson}1\color{crimson}122\color{crimson}1\color{crimson}122\color{crimson}2\color{crimson}222\color{crimson}1\color{crimson}111\color{crimson}3\color{crimson}33\ldots\;,$$

then

$$11212221133\ldots\;.\tag{2}$$

We can see from $(1)$ that the resulting string will end with $\ldots131(1)$, with the final $1$ in parentheses collapsing with the initial $1$ in the first vertex when we bend the list around into a circle. You could imagine writing out the list of $27$ vertices around a circle in the order in which the Euler circuit passes through them; then the second digit of the last vertex and the first digit of the first vertex collapse together just like all of the other linking pairs. The end result is a circular list of $27$ digits, three each of $1,2$, and $3$ — circular because we imagine it wrapped around in a circle so that the first digit immediately follows the last.

Since it has $27$ digits, it has $27$ three-digit substrings, like the $212$ that starts at position $3$ in $(2)$. That substring arises from the edge going from vertex $21$ to vertex $12$; we used that edge only once, so there can be only one $212$ substring. Thus, each of the $27$ possible three-digit substrings must be represented exactly once in our string.

I recommend that you try to find your own Euler circuit, but in case you get completely stuck, I’ve left the $27$-digit string resulting from my Euler circuit in the spoiler-protected block below.

> $112122211333232233123132131$

Comment: Thank you. Very clear- the circular arrangement isn't mentioned in the book from what I can tell, and this is a very thorough breakdown and explanation. Also appreciate the spoiler-protected blow :)

Comment: @Learner: You’re welcome.